# React-Native: Adding text limit Indicator with a custom TextInput component

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-textinput

What I want to accomplish is a textInput that show a text like (0/255) in the side of itself.

The minimal code for the component:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';
    
    export default function InputWithIndicator({ Limit, ...otherProps }) {
      const [charRemains, setCharRemains] = useState(0);
      const [TextValues, setTextValues] = useState('');
      const [TextLimit] = useState(Limit);
    useEffect(() => {
          setCharRemains(Limit-TextValues.length);
    });
    
     return (
        <View >
          <TextInput {...otherProps} onChangeText={value=>setTextValues(value)}/>
          <Text>
            {charRemains}/{TextLimit}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

To  place the component in code:

```
<InputWithIndicator placeholder="Your name" maxLength={25} Limit={25} onChangeText={value=>setName(value)} />
```

It works nice as component to display. But the major problem is the onChangeText does not return any value at all.
Is there any way? FYI, I have tried with onChange Event, too.

Comment: Actually, you are doing the simple task in a complex way, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onChange` instead fo `onChangeText`

Take a look at my sample: [Sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/remaining-input-letters-textinput)

Comment: The OP told they also tried `onChange` prop

Comment: @RajendranNadar Yes, but I failed retrieving the value as text as it was arrayed. He's shown me the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

This is live code https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/text-input-with-length-limit.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <TextInput
     style={styles.input}
     maxLength={TextLimit}
     onChangeText={(value) => setText(value)}
   />
   <Text>
     {TextLimit - text.length}/{TextLimit}
   </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I agree but this does not work as a component, the onChangeText part. I have more than 50 instances in my app, so a component is must. BTW, thanks for your suggestion, I took that part, too...

Comment: Yes, but you can directly invoke the setState on a parent component without using useEffect

Comment: I agreed on you this and also told you I already had implemented that in my component.